# Handling onActivityResult with nested activity

Tags: java, android

I have four activity (ActivityA, ActivityB, ActivityC, ActivityD) and ActivityA have onActivityResult method to do something.

Activity calling flow: ActivityA -> ActivityB -> ActivityC -> ActivityD so now ActivityD wanted to send intent result to ActivityA directly without interacting with ActivityB and ActivityC, but I am getting null in onActivityResult method of ActivityA.

Pleas suggest me how to achieve this, thanks.

Comment: activityResult can be captured only be the parent activity. One solution would be to pass the result back to all activities and call `finish()` on each `onActivityResult` callback

Comment: Just call startActivity(new Intent(ActivityD.this,ActivityA).putStringExtra("KEY","VALUE"));

Answer (score 0):

try with rx activity result ?

https://github.com/NateWickstrom/RxActivityResult